# How to fix Netbeans plugin error?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to install the EJB and EAR plugin and CSS Preprocessors plugin but get an error of

> Some plugins require plugin Editor Library to be installed.
>
> > The plugin Editor Library is requested in version >= 2.1 (release version 2) but only 3.46.1.22.43 (of release version different from 2) was found.
> >
> > > The following plugin is affected:
> > >
> > > > Generic Languages Framework - Refactorings

I have a windows 7 home premium 64 bit laptop with Netbeans 7.4 and java jdk 7 update 45.

How do I fix it so that I can get those two plugins updated on my Netbeans?